How to test this wire to see if it's neutral
I am trying to determine if I can have a smart dimmer switch installed to replace this old dual light switch. 
There is an unconnected wire that comes into the switch box on one side and runs out another side, without connecting to anything, nor is it pigtailed into a wire cap like neutral wires often are. It is in an old apartment building in a country where building codes are not always followed. The colors of the wires can not be assumed to be correct or indicative of any standard, since the colors are inconsistent in various outlets and switches throughout the apartment.  There is no dedicated ground wire in this switch box.
What I would like to know is how can I test this wire to determine if it is an actual neutral or not?  It might seem obvious that it is or should be, but I would like to confirm it by testing.  Most smart dimmer switches require a neutral wire to work properly, so if this wire is not one I need to find another solution.  Online most advice describes identifying a neutral wire by testing it with a ground wire, but since this box has no ground wire, I'm not sure how to test it.
I'd like to verify this wire is a neutral before ordering switches and having an "electrician" install them. "Electricians" in this country are usually just some handy-ish guy who is likely to simply wire in any switch, without checking that it will work beforehand, and then looking stumped when it doesn't work, at which point he will simply state that it won't work, and ask for his payment. I would like to know a smart dimmer switch can be installed before I have the landlord's "electrician" come over.


if you measure 120 volts between the hot and the wire in question, it is neutral

Do the light switches need to be on, or does it matter?

the switch switches the hot

It looks like conduit might be used for the wires.  If so, the box might be grounded by the conduit.  Neutral should read ~0v to ground.  Hot/live to ground(box) and neutral will read local voltage.

It reads about 120 volts between hot and the mystery wire, so it seems to be a neutral.
